# Can an I make this "block wrapping" optional in a idiomatic/neat way?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, you can call a remote api like this

```
def get_remote_date
  Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.json')
end
```

If you do `gem install vcr`, you can do this

```
def get_remote_date
  VCR.use_cassette("cassette_001") do
    Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.json')
  end
end
```

Vcr recording/playback helps during development, when 
the remote api is expensive.
Whether to use vcr or not should be optional, indicated
by the first argument of the function:

```
def get_remote_date(should_use_vcr)
  VCR.use_cassette("cassette_001") do
    Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.json')
  end
end
```

My question is, how do I rewrite the method so that the "block wrapping" / "VCR.use_cassette("cassette_001") do" is conditional on the boolean value of the should_use_vcr local variable.

I could do

```
def get_remote_date(should_use_vcr)
  if conditional here
    VCR.use_cassette("cassette_001") do
      Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.json')
    end
  else
    Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.json')     
  end
end
```

but for a complex method that has "Net::HTTP.get( " plus a dozen more lines, there's too much duplication of code,
so looking for a neater way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following approach:

```
def get_remote_date
  record_request { Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.json') }
end

def record_request(&request)
  ENV['RECORD_REQUEST'] ? VCR.use_cassette("cassette_001", &request) : request.call
end
```

This is a nice [article](https://mixandgo.com/learn/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes), which explains what does `&block` (ampersand parameter) mean and how it relates to `yield` keyword.

Comment: Docs for `#call` can be found [there](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Proc.html#method-i-call).

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating a yield based solution,

```
  def maybe_cache_http_requests(cassette)
    if ENV['CACHE_HTTP_REQUESTS'] == "1"
      require 'vcr'
      VCR.configure do |config|
        config.cassette_library_dir = "vcr_cassettes"
        config.hook_into :webmock
      end
      VCR.use_cassette(cassette) do
        yield
      end
    else
      yield
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could put the duplicate code into a method and call that method either wrapped in the VCR do block or without VCR.

Comment: can yield help here?

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior I don't think so, but my ruby is a bit rusty. Does creating a method not work with VCR or why do you ask about yield?